# How to get the href attribute with clipboard.js?

Tags: javascript, html, href, clipboard.js

Im trying to get the href attribute after a button click,but I cannot make it work.

My code:

```
    <!-- Target -->
    <a href='https://clipboardjs.com/' id='foo'/>

 <!-- Trigger -->  
<button class='btn' data-clipboard-target='#foo'>
    Copy to clipboard
</button>  

<script type="text/javascript">
        new Clipboard(".btn", {
          text: function(trigger) {
            return $(trigger).getAttribute("href");
          }
        });
</script>
```

Any Ideas?

Thank You

Comment: what do you mean by cannot make it work? are there any errors? what does happen if you click on it?

Comment: Reading through the [docs](https://clipboardjs.com/) the constructor is: `ClipboardJS` not `Clipboard`...maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
new ClipboardJS(".btn", {
  text: function(trigger) {
    const query = trigger.getAttribute('data-clipboard-target');
    const target = document.querySelector(query);
    return target.getAttribute('href');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<!-- Target -->
<a href='https://clipboardjs.com/' id='foo'></a>

 <!-- Trigger -->  
<button class='btn' data-clipboard-target='#foo'>
    Copy to clipboard
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you it works but what about using simple javascript without jquery new ClipboardJS('.btn', {
    target: function(trigger) {
        return trigger.getAttribute('href');
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

`getAttribute` is a Native DOM method, which you cannot directly apply to a jQuery wrapped element. Either you need to get the Native DOM element out or use the `attr()` method of jQuery to get the value of `href`:

```
$(trigger)[0].getAttribute("href");
// OR
$(trigger).attr("href");
```